# Find angle in quadrilateral

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

[image]Given two adjacent angles, AOB and BOC, each of 60 degrees, construct the bisector of angle BCO, which intersects OA in D.
Find the angle BDC.

Source (Romanian Math Magazine - Gazeta Matematica; online competition)

Drawing: https://pasteboard.co/KbDzeCx.jpg

Trying the drawing in Geogebra, I found the angle is 30 degrees, regardless of value of angle C (moving B on the bisector OB). Is there some theorem which I could use to derive this?

From the figure, BDO = 90 - BCD (also don't know how to prove it).

I am interested in a solution for elementary school students.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

**Theorem** : In a triangle bisector of an interior angle and bisector of other two exterior angles meet at a point.

$$\angle AOM=60$$

Since $CD$ is the interior bisector of $\angle BOC$ and $OD$ is the exterior bisector of $\angle BOD$ of $\triangle BOC$ (one interior bisector and one exterior bisector) meet at $D$, $BD$ is the bisector of $\angle OBN$.

$$\alpha +60=\beta + \theta$$

$$2\alpha +60=2\beta,\alpha +30=\beta (*)$$
$(*)$exterior $\angle$ of $\triangle BOC$

$$\theta=30$$

Answer (score 2):

Added: As @lionheart pointed out, wrt $\triangle OBC$, the internal angle bisector of $\angle OCB$, and the external angle bisector of $\angle COB$ meet at D, then DB is the external angle bisector of $\angle CBO$. Thus, we have $s = s$ as shown.

[image]

After producing DB to cut the y-axis at T, we can always draw the circle passing through T, D, O. Next, we need to prove that C is also a con-cyclic point of that circle. This is done by the following:-

Using  "exterior angle of triangle" twice, we have $s = 30^0 + t$ and $2s = 2x + 60^0$. Consequently, $x = t$.

---

On one hand, we have $x + y = 60^0$

On the other hand, we have $t + 90^0 + y + z = 180^0$

Result follows.